# How to use Azure AD access_token and id_token

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have registered two applications in Azure AD, a .Net core web API and a single page react application. I configured these applications to get the id_token for the react client application and an access token for consuming the web API when the user signs in to the client application. I need to send user-specific information to my API when the user signs in (I need to get a unique id from the token to identify the user). Some document says we can't send the id_token to the API since it is issued for the client application. and some says we can't send the user-specific information via access token since it should be used for authorization purpose only.

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

In the context of Open Id connect, is it ok to send user-specific information via access token? I want a unique id from the token and store it in my system to identify the user. if it is ok to use the access token, Which claim is best suited for this purpose (sub or oid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that you should not send the id_token to the API. One option is to include the necessary user information as claims inside the access token. Alternatively you could try to ask AzureAD for the user details when the API receives the access token. Azure for example provides the UserInfo endpoint for this.

See this page [Microsoft identity platform UserInfo endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo)